# Simple C# concurrency / multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm probably missing something basic here, but still would appreciate your kind help in understanding this. So I have the following simple multithreaded program I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //            List<int> outcome = new List<int>();
            Test t = new Test();

                Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(t.call1));
                Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(t.call2));
                thread1.Start();
                thread2.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(3000); //Give enough time for threads to end
                Console.Write("{0},", t.mSum);
                t.mSum = 0;
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        public int mSum = 0;
        public void call1()
        {
            //lock (this)
            //{

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello Thread 1, mSum value: {0}", mSum);
                mSum = mSum + 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye Thread 1, mSum value: {0}", mSum);
            }
            //}
            //  Console.WriteLine(mSum);
        }
        public void call2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello Thread 2, mSum value: {0}",mSum);
                mSum = mSum + 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye Thread 2, mSum value: {0}",mSum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I would expect this output to be nondetermenistic because context switching can occur anytime right? But when I run the program, I get the following output (only a part of the output, malformed due to my poor stackoverflow.com question posting skills):

```
Hello Thread 1, mSum value: 62    Goodbye Thread 1, mSum value: 63   
Hello Thread 1, mSum value: 63    Goodbye Thread 1, mSum value: 64   
Hello Thread 2, mSum value: 59    Goodbye Thread 2, mSum value: 65   
Hello Thread 2, mSum value: 65    Goodbye Thread 2, mSum value: 66
```

So, assuming I wrote this right, and mSum is indeed shared between the threads (looks like it...) - how can I explain line no. 3? Thread 2 reads 59, adds 1 and then we get 65!

Did I discover a new kind of math? :)

Comment: And this is in the correct order with no restructuring? The code shows that there should be a line break between the "Hello" line and the "Goodbye" line, and if you removed that it is fine, I'm just trying to get a feel to make sure it went "Hello 1, goodbye 1... hello 2, goodbye 2" If you know what I"m saying

Comment: Yes the order is correct: left to right, then up to bottom (62->63,63->64,59->65,65->66). I tried to add an image here but couldn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not locking the shared variable `mSum`, and `mSum = mSum + 1` is not an atomic operation. And it should be obvious that printing to console, incrementing a variable and then printing to console again is not atomic all the more :) There are many possible ways the threads may interlace. For example:

> 1) mSum = 0 [Thread1 is working]
>
> 2) mSum = 1 [Thread1 is working]
>
> 3) mSum = 2 [Thread2 is working]
>
> 4) ...
>
> 5) mSum = 59 [Thread2 is working] and it gets pre-empted after "Hello..."
>
> 6) mSum = 60 [Thread1 is working]
>
> 7) mSum = 61 [Thread1 is working]
>
> 8) ...
>
> 9) mSum = 64 [Thread2 is working] awaken just before incrementation line Thread2 continues, and calculates 65

In `5)` `Thread2` could've been pre-empted even after reading mSum from memory in `mSum = mSum + 1` but before calculating `mSum + 1`.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using multiple threads, the value may well have changed between the first and second `Console.WriteLine` call.

If you want to make sure you are reporting the correct value that the addition will use, you'll have to use a lock.

Answer (score 1):

The mSum is changed from 2 threads A and B at the same time between the first WriteLine and second WriteLine mSum might be changed. mSum is not locked or volatile so you do not have any barrier in the memory so you might became a very strange results but it is  depending on you CPU type and cash.

Just put the word volatile before the mSum that means mSum will be not cashed in the CPU. Run the application again and see the console!?

Comment: It seems like no matter how many times I run the program, the end result for mSum is always 200 even with no locks. I have done so numerous times.

Comment: @Tal Just because the race conditions exist doesn't mean they happen every single time.  The while idea is that they might or might not happen.  Different race conditions also have different probabilities of occurring, possibly affected by other behaviors.  For example, you might run that same program on a different machine with more/less cores, or more/less general power, and get a different result.  If your program breaks .01% of the time is that acceptable to you?  Perhaps it is, in this case.  Would you care if your bank missed a check deposit .01% of the time?

Comment: @Tal importent to know that You can't read the same bit of memory twice at the same point in time. The nuts and guts of it are quite complex though, as a modern multi-core CPU maintains all sorts of cache about these sorts of things.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, `mSum` is being shared between multiple threads, the resolution would either be a lock, or turn `mSum` into an `volatile` integer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx

So you could change this:

```
public int mSum = 0;
```

To:

```
public volatile int mSum = 0;
```

But as others pointed out, in more complex situations, you might want to use a lock.

Also, there is no need to wrap your call in a new instance of `ThreadStart`, so instead of this:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(t.call1));
```

You could do this:

```
new Thread(t.call1);
```

Comment: Hi, I know this is not thread-safe and I know I should have used a lock to *solve* this but I'm just trying to understand how .NET works internally through this code. That being said, mSum is shared but I try to understand the logic.

Comment: It isn't really shared, it's just accessed from multiple threads. As said by Sean, the value of mSum could change between the WriteLine and the addition.